# How to simplify the @import path for my npm sass package?

Tags: import, npm, sass

## Situation

I have developed a small **sass package** and published it on **npm**.

To use the package in a project I `npm install` it and then import the main file like so:

`@import 'node_modules/my-package/my-package.scss';`

This works.

## Question

Is it possible to allow users to just import it like so?

`@import 'my-package';` 
or
`@import 'my-package.scss';`

I think I saw some packages that allow this.
Is this possible?

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gulp and gulp-sass, people can specify `includePaths`

```
.pipe(sass({
    includePaths: [
        './node_modules/your-package-name'
    ]
}))
```

This will tell the compiler to always look for includes by appending that path to import as it is compiling.

Then in their *.scss files they only need to do

```
@import "your-package-name";
```

or

```
@import "your-package-name/variables";
```

Otherwise, I don't think it's possible with similar setup - after all, it's just an URL, unless they do some pre-processing, they would need to specify the full path to it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This setup with gulp was probably what I saw. I'll have to stick to the full path then. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Dart Sass, you can pass `--load-path=node_modules` to your watch script and then in your main Sass file add `@import "my-package";`.

Example script in `package.json`:

`"sass --load-path=node_modules --watch app/sass:app/dist --style compressed"`

---

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and installing modules I didn't need before stumbling across this solution.

Comment: Is it the same if the imported package is a scoped package? `@my-package`

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Shouldn't be a problem, I don't think.